# Changing the QtLabel on every message received using mqtt

Tags: python, pyqt4, mqtt

I am trying to change my qt label and update it every time I will receive the
data coming from the esp8266. I am looking for suggestions in order to do that

```
def initGui(self):

    self.labelMCdata = QtGui.QLabel("%")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):

    global x
    x = str(msg.payload)
    print(msg.topic+" "+ x )
```

I don't know if it is possible to attach a `self.labelMCdata.setText` on the 
on_message method because everytime I call the initGUI function there is always an error.

I am using the command`self.initGui()` to call the function but since it is not defined on the on_message, I cannot proceed. When I try to add another argument on the on_message method it says that only 3 is available I don't know if it is limited to that.

Answer (score 0):

if the on_message method is inside the same class of the qt gui the you can access the label directly:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):

    global x
    x = str(msg.payload)
    self.ui.labelMCdata.settext("my message here!")
    print(msg.topic+" "+ x )
```

Comment: `settext` or `setText`?

Comment: NameError: global name 'self' is not defined, I assume that because on the on_message() method it does not have an attribute named 'self', although I have tried to add another parameter named 'self', I do think that the function  that pertains to 'on_message' has fixed parameters. But please enlighten me because I am unsure of it.

Comment: Btw I have used the QTimer() method which will call a method capable of rendering the UI every for second since I have assigned a global variable accessing it on a different method has been possible.

Comment: Although I am looking for possible solutions which can help me understand mqtt and qt GUI more. Thanks for the input